# Java Mail Api getting stuck at "220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready"

Tags: java, outlook, smtp, jakarta-mail

So I'm trying to send mail using corporate email using smtp. ie. smtp.office365.com
I've tried every possible way to code it, but every time it gets stuck on **220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready**

[Code](https://gist.github.com/brunocesarsilva/12a529f7f752f2853b9f)

**Debug Op**

```
    DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.5.1   
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers   
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers  
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map  
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]  
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true  
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false  
220 xxxxxxxxx.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Fri, 23 Mar 2018 15:39:34 +0000  
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "smtp.office365.com", port: 587   

EHLO xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  
250-xxxxxxxxx.outlook.office365.com Hello [xxx.xxx.xxx.xx]  
250-SIZE 157286400  
250-PIPELINING  
250-DSN  
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES  
250-STARTTLS  
250-8BITMIME  
250-BINARYMIME  
250-CHUNKING  
250 SMTPUTF8  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "157286400"  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "DSN", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "BINARYMIME", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""  
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SMTPUTF8", arg ""  
STARTTLS  
220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
```

Can anyone explain this.

Comment: You're stuck at `STARTTLS` - it's trying to turn on **encryption**. See *trying to connect to host "smtp.office365.com", port 587, isSSL false*? Turn `SSL` on.

Comment: Thankyou for responding. I'm using **tls** " properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");"

Comment: [SSLNOTES.txt](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/SSLNOTES.txt) contains debugging tips.  Also, change your code to catch Exception to make sure you're not getting a RuntimeException.